# which REST API git client is calling

Tags: git, github, github-api, github-api-v3

I wonder, if there is a way to know which API git client is calling for the command?

For example, how to tell which API git client is calling for `git log`. Is there any generic way of discovering this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can activate the [Git Trace2 API](https://git-scm.com/docs/api-trace2) in order to see what is going on during a `git log` call, or any other commands:

Example (for `git version`)

```bash
export GIT_TRACE2=~/log.normal
$ git version
git version 2.20.1.155.g426c96fcdb

$ cat ~/log.normal
12:28:42.620009 common-main.c:38                  version 2.20.1.155.g426c96fcdb
12:28:42.620989 common-main.c:39                  start git version
12:28:42.621101 git.c:432                         cmd_name version (version)
12:28:42.621215 git.c:662                         exit elapsed:0.001227 code:0
12:28:42.621250 trace2/tr2_tgt_normal.c:124       atexit elapsed:0.001265 code:0
```

The trace2 API was introduced with [Git 2.22 (Q2 2019)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56094711/6309).