# git submodule update --recursive does not work but navigating inside repo and git cloning does work

Tags: git

I've been having issues with my submodules downloading with my master repo.
Once I clone a repo, if I run `git submodule update --recursive` the command just sits there for forever. It'll sit there all day long, I let it do it all day one day to make sure it wasn't because of waiting for downloading the files or something. (I have also tried `git submodule update --init` and `git submodule update --init --recursive`)

But if I `cd` into the area where the submodule is and manually do a `git clone https://somewhere.git` to download the submodule/repo into the correct place, it works fine.

I would just like this to be cohesive and all together in a single command

Any ideas?

Comment: have you used the exact same url as the one mentioned in the `.gitmodules` file at the root of your repo ?

Comment: Could this be related to your subrepos referencing each other and therefore inifitely run with `--recursive`?

Answer (score 0):

Try and activate the [Trace2 API](https://git-scm.com/docs/api-trace2) ([Git 2.22+, Q2 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56094711/6309)), to check what operation is done, and from which point you start waiting forever.

```bash
export GIT_TRACE2_EVENT=~/log.event
git submodule update --recursive
```

As an alternative, try and a [`git clone --recurse-submodules`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---recurse-submodulesltpathspecgt) to check if the clone can initialize the submodules, instead of your separate command.

Comment: Thank you! I will be trying this! Just need a little help to see what is going on, this will surely help me figure out where the hangup is and didn't know where to start. I have tried the `git clone --recurse-submodules` and it suffers from the same issue but thank you for mentioning it