# Being asked for authentication when git cloning a repository. Only able to authenticate it through a PAT and no other method (signing in or ssh) Why?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, github, github-actions

I created a new repository and when trying to clone it using terminal "git clone" command I am being asked to authenticate. I tried authenticate by signing in but it doesn't allow me to click the authenticate git-ecosystem option. Even fails for ssh. Why was I only able through a PAT?
Please explain

Tried changing some setting but no use.

Comment: You could try and look at Git debug output, see [How can I debug git/git-shell related problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6178401/3266847). Maybe that'll show why SSH doesn't work.

Comment: How is your remote configured? Do you connect through git@github or https?

Answer (score 0):

By your post I can't tell if you've set up your github repo and account with the ssh key. I've done this set up many times so far and recently started using vs code. I see this tagged with visual studio code so I assume you want to use that integrated source control tool for your commits later. So you'll need to use a .pub key like i did. You won't be able to use a .ppk with that in case you have that set up in your repo like i did. I used to use a .ppk that I generated using puttygen on my windows machine. Visual studio code will not work with ppk. So I converted the ppk with puttygen by exporting it as open ssh and giving it a .pub extension. make sure the private key is in your .ssh.

FYI, I don't know what "PAT" is so forgive me if that was important here.

The following article was helpful to me in understanding procedure. However it doesn't use puttygen for the key generation. I have summarized the contents below. Have fun!!

Source: [Using ssh to clone a Private Git repository with VsCode and Git Bash](https://medium.com/@melvingrooms/using-ssh-to-clone-a-private-hit-repository-9fbe79a589cd#:%7E:text=click%20add%20ssh%20key.,the%20link%20copied%20from%20GitHub)

1. Prerequisites:

   - GitHub account
   - Visual Studio Code (Vscode)
   - Git CLI
2. Create a new private repository on GitHub:

   - Login to GitHub.
   - Select "New repository" and make it private.
   - Add a name, .gitignore, and README.md.
   - Create the repository.
3. Open Visual Studio Code (Vscode):

   - Open a new terminal.
   - Switch to the Git Bash shell.
4. Create and navigate to a new directory:

   - Create a new directory: `mkdir <name-of-directory>`
   - Change into the new directory: `cd <name-of-directory>`
5. Generate SSH keypair:

   - Run `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096` in the terminal.
   - Press Enter three times (use the default path).
   - Optionally, add a passphrase for added security.
6. Copy the public key to GitHub:

   - Navigate to the directory where the key is saved (e.g., .ssh).
   - List files: `ls`
   - Open the public key file: `cat id_rsa.pub`
   - Copy the text.
7. Add SSH key to GitHub:

   - In GitHub, click profile picture, select "Settings."
   - Under settings, select "SSH and GPG keys."
   - Add a new SSH key, paste the copied public key, and click "Add SSH key."
8. Clone the repository using SSH:

   - Go to the desired repository on GitHub.
   - Copy the SSH link.
   - In the terminal, navigate to the directory created to save the cloned repo.
   - Run `git clone <ssh-link-from-GitHub>`
   - Type "yes" when prompted.
9. Open the cloned repository in Vscode:

   - Go to "File," open a file, and select the file with the name of the cloned repo.

   > Congratulations!
   > You have successfully cloned your private GitHub repository using SSH and Vscode.