# Nested Git repositories

Tags: git

As I mentioned in a [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9669882/slow-git-operations/9673060#9673060), Git is running very slowly (2.5 hours for status) for a repository of my size (about 6 million files). I decided to try and break up the repository into pieces which Git can manage. The repository consists of tests so I created one repository for each test. I would like to have another repository which manages the hierarchy of how the tests are organized. An example is shown below:

```
tests
tests/suite1/case1
tests/suite1/case2
tests/suite2/case1
...
```

I then tried to create the parent repository. "git init" and "git add ." all went smoothly. However, I'm unable to add those as submodules. Git seems to want to check it out when I add them. Is it possible to have a submodule that's not a remote repository like this? Also, even though "git add" was very fast on the parent repository "git status" was still very slow - I guess it doesn't skip the .git directories!

Comment: It is quite strange that you have a single project with 6 millions individual files. (what kind of files are they? Even large software projects don't have millions of source files)? Looks like a version control system might be the wrong tool. Did you consider something else?

Comment: For nesting git repositories you should use git submodule.

Comment: It is a test repository, created from artifacts provided by our customers. It is all human generated but not by humans that work in my company. We want to put it under version control because we sometimes have to modify the tests and would like a history of the modifications. Often times, we have different versions of the tests for different versions of the software as well. This is the standard VCS problem, albeit in a different scenario than typically encountered.

Comment: Fitness acceptance test framework actually does something like this for you. It is wiki based and I'm pretty sure it handles versioning as well.