# Git hangs indefinitely after pushing to a large repo

Tags: git, github

I am pushing a git folder -10 gigs big and it gets stuck after:

```
> C:\FIS>git push -u -v origin master Pushing to
> https://xxx/kaulk/FIS.git Username for
> 'https://xxx': kaulk Password for
> 'https://xxx': Counting objects: 393927, done.
> Delta compression using up to 4 threads. Compressing objects: 100%
> (106741/106741), done. POST git-receive-pack (chunked)93927), 484.62
> MiB | 27.60 MiB/s
```

I have already increased the git buffer space and have the latest git installations but to no help.

Also the non verbose log is :

```
C:\FIS>git push -u -f origin master
Username for 'https://github.dowjones.net': kaulk
Password for 'https://kaulk@github.dowjones.net':
Counting objects: 393927, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (106741/106741), done.
Writing objects: 100% (393927/393927), 737.64 MiB | 6.22 MiB/s, done.
Total 393927 (delta 298221), reused 365855 (delta 272814)
```

So it does compress it to less than 1 gb.

Comment: Why so large? I don't know who your host is but GitHub recommends repo sizes less than 1 GB: https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota

Answer (score 0):

Well you could push it chunk by chunk or folder by folder.

E.g. you have 3 folders:

```
Folder_1 (3 gig)
Folder_2 (2.5 gig)
Folder_3 (4 gig)
```

You could then call:

```
git init
git add Folder_1
git commit -m "Added first folder"
git push
git add Folder_2
git commit -m "Added second folder"
git push
git add Folder_3
git commit -m "Added third folder"
git push
```

Git should then be able to accept your commits.
Also pay attention that if you are using github:
It does not play well with files larger than 50 MB. See [GitHub-Help](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-large-files)

Comment: Still hangs at the same spot.

Comment: That is strange. Stopped it after the first folder or later?

Comment: stopped on the first go itself

Comment: Mhm... running out of ideas, you could try pushing the folders in different order?

Your log shows that git itself has no problem with the folders but your repository may have problems accepting it. So it could either work if you wait a little bit or there is a corrupted file somewhere...

Comment: I did git fsck which showed the repository integrity to be fine too so am majorly stuck in this.

Comment: I have found another interesting post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175715/git-push-takes-forever

I would try to switch the protocol first: See [Basic URL Rewriting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10729634/3281871)