# GitHub sync not working. git push super slow

Tags: git, github

We have a large project ~13gb. We can commit it just fine to the github software (had to commit in sections). But upon trying to sync the commits to the repo it fails. doing git status tells us that we are ahead of the master by 4 commits and to use git push. git push starts working but is extremely slow. (120kbps) Is this normal?

Answer (score 1):

In addition of **[disk quota](https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota/)** which might make the push fail anyway, git push can be slow for a number of reasons:

- [`git gc` applied on your local repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15198952/6309) before the push can help.
- [ssh settings](http://blog.netflowdevelopments.com/2015/03/11/slow-git-push-pull-speeds-try-tweaking-your-ssh-settings/) (if pushed using an ssh url)
- network issues (check what a `git push --verbose` does return)

Comment: Well its saying to try and keep it under 1gb? how would we accomplish this while still being able to work on github?

Comment: @Kuliu at least try and push only the first few commits (instead of the few history), to see if that actually completes.

Comment: @Kuliu But also consider that git is not well suited for such large repositories: splitting it in several repos (while keeping the original history) is the general best practice.