# git status command is very slow

Tags: git

My `git status` command is getting slow recently.

I tried to trace the execution:

```
GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=2 git status
```

Output:

```
10:24:26.589696 run-command.c:640       trace: run_command: GIT_INDEX_FILE=.git/index git submodule summary --cached --for-status --summary-limit 1 HEAD
10:24:26.611043 git.c:576               trace: exec: git-submodule summary --cached --for-status --summary-limit 1 HEAD
10:24:26.611744 run-command.c:640       trace: run_command: git-submodule summary --cached --for-status --summary-limit 1 HEAD
10:24:26.688245 git.c:576               trace: exec: git-sh-i18n--envsubst --variables 'usage: $dashless $USAGE'
10:24:26.688921 run-command.c:640       trace: run_command: git-sh-i18n--envsubst --variables 'usage: $dashless $USAGE'
10:24:26.712823 git.c:576               trace: exec: git-sh-i18n--envsubst 'usage: $dashless $USAGE'
10:24:26.713851 run-command.c:640       trace: run_command: git-sh-i18n--envsubst 'usage: $dashless $USAGE'
10:24:26.754163 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --git-dir
10:24:26.773008 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --git-path objects
10:24:26.788905 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git rev-parse -q --git-dir
10:24:26.832189 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --show-prefix
10:24:26.847857 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --show-toplevel
10:24:26.865076 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git rev-parse -q --verify --default HEAD HEAD
10:24:26.887339 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --show-toplevel
10:24:26.901182 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --sq --prefix  --
10:24:26.927138 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git diff-index --cached --ignore-submodules=dirty --raw d6f45eab9517deee0ad8c898ec74b6ce876ba9eb --
10:24:26.941160 run-command.c:640       trace: run_command: GIT_INDEX_FILE=.git/index git submodule summary --files --for-status --summary-limit 1
10:24:26.962172 git.c:576               trace: exec: git-submodule summary --files --for-status --summary-limit 1
10:24:26.962895 run-command.c:640       trace: run_command: git-submodule summary --files --for-status --summary-limit 1
10:24:37.013868 git.c:576               trace: exec: git-sh-i18n--envsubst --variables 'usage: $dashless $USAGE'
10:24:37.014548 run-command.c:640       trace: run_command: git-sh-i18n--envsubst --variables 'usage: $dashless $USAGE'
10:24:37.035160 git.c:576               trace: exec: git-sh-i18n--envsubst 'usage: $dashless $USAGE'
10:24:37.035863 run-command.c:640       trace: run_command: git-sh-i18n--envsubst 'usage: $dashless $USAGE'
10:24:37.064778 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --git-dir
10:24:37.088144 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --git-path objects
10:24:37.106468 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git rev-parse -q --git-dir
10:24:37.144214 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --show-prefix
10:24:37.163255 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --show-toplevel
10:24:37.184273 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git rev-parse -q --verify --default HEAD
10:24:37.201302 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --show-toplevel
10:24:37.220281 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --sq --prefix  --
10:24:37.249722 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git diff-files --ignore-submodules=dirty --raw --
```

And I found in the two steps it take 10 seconds:

```
10:24:26.962895 run-command.c:640       trace: run_command: git-submodule summary --files --for-status --summary-limit 1
10:24:37.013868 git.c:576               trace: exec: git-sh-i18n--envsubst --variables 'usage: $dashless $USAGE'
```

My git environment:

- macOS 10.13.4 (17E199)
- git version 2.17.0

Is there anyone coming into the same issue? I'm not familiar with the details with Git.

Comment: Is your repo dirty? What about the staging area? How many files are tracked? Have you tried *git gc*?

Comment: probably you will get more details if you run the submodule command with GIT_TRACE defined

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For files you do not track, see also "[UNTRACKED FILES AND PERFORMANCE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74889434/6309)" with `git status`.

Try first to check if the presence of submodules might influence the `git status` performance, using the [`--ignore-submodules[=<when>]` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#git-status---ignore-submodulesltwhengt):

```
git status --ignore-submodules=all
```

Also, make sure your repo is clone locally, not on a remote drive, which would add latency to any Git operation.

Comment: thanks @VonC, by add `--ignore-submodules=all` it works fine ! but why checking submodules is slow?

Comment: @EvansY. By default, git always check submodule status, but you can configure them to be ignored.

Comment: You can try to change into the directory of that subrepo, and issue the same analysis command like in the top repository.

Answer (score 4):

I am afraid this is not just with git status, maybe the whole git environment is lagging.
Check this https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/Diagnosing-why-Git-is-so-slow out.

Comment: That link is from 2015, and is no longer relevant. Current performance issue are being addressed, for instance, in https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1533#issuecomment-384259846. ... for Git for Windows though (the OP is on Mac)